# Making every symbol bold with exceptions / exclusion list

Tags: math-mode, formatting, conditionals, bold

I would like to have a command that makes everything bold (in math-mode), except for some specified list of exceptions.

For example, a command `\boldformula` that makes every symbol bold apart from parentheses, so that

```
\boldformula{ a \ast ( b \ast c) }
```

becomes equivalent to

```
\bm{a \ast} ( \bm{b \ast c} )
```

Any suggestion?

*Edit:* In response to a comment from egreg. I would like the bold formulas to coexist peacefully with the rest of the math environment, preserving alignments, paired delimiter etc.

If it is easier, a command that makes selectively bold some symbols would also be great. For example, one that makes bold alfanumeric characters in the standard math-font, \ast, \subset, \cap and leaves everything else untouched would already be of great help.

Comment: probably it should be more easy to use your editor replace function using regexps. Select formula and replace \\([^()]+\\) with \\boldsymbol{\1}

Comment: This is a valid point. However I am working on a long text and I am afraid that using search and replace will end up doing more harm than good: since I am not experienced with regexps it seeems all too easy to screw something up and only realize about it after days of work.

Comment: Are these formulas to appear next to normal ones in the same display? Do you need support for `align` or similar? What are the exceptions? Do you need support for extensible delimiters? What math font are you employing? If you clarify those specifications quite a big amount of work would be needed. It's possibly easier to do the other way around, that is, presenting a list of the symbols to be in boldface.

Comment: The answers to your yes/no questions should be `yes'. However, I am more than happy to go with the opposite approach and specify a list of symbols to make bold. Such a macro would already go a long way to solve my problem, and I can do the few remaining cases by hand. (I edited the question accordingly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vigolo_embolden_command:N
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cN { __vigolo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 : } #1
  \cs_set_protected:Npn #1 { \bm { \use:c { __vigolo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 : } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vigolo_embolden_char:n
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \mathchardef { __vigolo_#1: } = \mathcode`#1 \scan_stop:
  \cs_set_protected:cn { __vigolo_#1_bold: } { \bm { \use:c { __vigolo_#1: } } }
  \char_set_active_eq:nc { `#1 } { __vigolo_#1_bold: }
  \mathcode`#1 = "8000 \scan_stop:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vigolo_embolden:
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN
   {% fill up
    A,B,C,D,
    a,b,c,d,
    *,+,-,
   }
   \vigolo_embolden_char:n
  \clist_map_function:nN
   {% fill up
    \ast,\langle,\rangle,\rightarrow,\to,\subset,
   }
   \vigolo_embolden_command:N
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\boldformula}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \vigolo_embolden:
  #1
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\boldformula{ a \ast ( b \ast c)\subset A }+abc$

$\bm{ a \ast ( b \ast c)\subset A }+abc$ (for comparison)

\end{document}
```

Only specific objects are declared to be emboldened in the scope of `\boldformula`. More work would be needed for delimiters, I guess.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does work! However, I admit that I do not understand your code: I am only familiar with old style latex commands (and even then I do not qualify as expert). Would you care to explain what is happening/provide references to understand it?

Comment: Your solution seems to struggle handling subscripts and superscripts: on `\boldformula{a_b}` I receive an error (missing { inserted). Do you think this can be fixed?

Comment: I solved by using `\boldformula{a_{b}}`.

Answer (score 0):

In `unicode-math`, you can load a lighter weight of a math family with the `range=` option, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS Math Bold}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range=\ast]

\begin{document}
\[ A \ast B \ast C \]
\end{document}
```

Minion Math and KP Math are some font families that come in several weights.

Unfortunately, the `range=` and `version=` arguments of `\setmathfont` are not compatible with each other, as of 2020.  So, if you do this, you cannot also use `\boldmath` or `\boldsymbol`  This prevents us from defining this as a math style that we can turn off and on.

Otherwise, one way to accomplish this is to wrap the bold symbols in `\boldsymbol{}`.  It would also be possible to adapt the `\boldsymbol` code from `amsbsy.sty` to switch to `\mathversion{normal}` instead of `\mathversion{bold}`.  You could then do something like `\let\oldast=\ast` and `\renewcommand\ast{\normalsymbol{\oldast}}`.  If you can create your own math fonts, you could also declare the normal and bold fonts as separate math symbol fonts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I really do not understand what you mean. My knowledge of tex&fonts is too patchy...